# Determining that reader has closed when using tee() function in Linux

Tags: c, linux

When using the [`tee()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/tee) system call to move data from one pipe to another, it returns 0 if the writer on the input pipe closes, but how can one discern whether the reader on the output pipe has closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future generations, it looks like the answer is that `tee()` will return -1 signalling an error, with `errno` set to EPIPE, when the reader of the pipe has closed it, even though this isn't documented in the man pages.  Correspondingly, a SIGPIPE will be generated, so be sure to properly handle that if you value your program continuing to execute.

Comment: An alternative to handling SIGPIPE is to ignore it; the `write()`-related calls then return an error and indicate the problem with `errno` set to EPIPE.  If `tee()` can generate a SIGPIPE (reasonable), then you must have been handling or ignoring SIGPIPE in order to get the `-1` and `EPIPE` status.